# AndEngine custom sprites

Tags: android, character, andengine, sprite

I started using andEngine yesterday but I'm pretty confused.. I want to make a custom character for each player, so i want to make a database inside the app in Assets/gfx and if for example the player chose a different eyes or nose, the character will change. Is there any way to build something like this without making different sprites and setting up the positions and all of that. (there are some games on the computer that does what i want to do with my app like maplestory, LaTale, Gust online, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure it is done this way (I never had a game where I used it, nor tried it), but here is an idea that came to my mind now:

Lets say we have a game with character appearance editing like maplestory. To make it simple, a character is just a circle, or a 2d ball, and you can change it's color and it's eyes color. So you have these folders:

```
assets/gfx/circles
```

And

```
assets/gfx/eyes
```

Now, lets say we have this circle:

[image: Red circle]

And we have these eyes:

[image: Yellow eyes]

And we want to combine them.

You could do it:

```
    BitmapTextureAtlas playerTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256 TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    TextureRegion playerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(playerTextureAtlas, this, "circles/redcircle.png", 0, 0);
    //By executing the next line, we place the eyes over the player texture area.
    //There is NO need to keep a reference to the texture region this returns to us, because technically this one and playerTextureRegion are THE SAME - they both hold the same region in the texture (As long as they have the same sizes, of course)
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(playerTextureAtlas, this, "eyes/yelloweyes.png", 0, 0);
```

Remember - the eyes image background has to be transperant so it won't override the circle! Play around with the `TextureOptions` parameter. I'm not sure if the one I used will fill this purpose - maybe another one will.

And lastly, you should keep the eyes eyes and circles the same size, since this way it is easier to test whether they fit. If you make the eyes just be a small rectangle, you will have to mess with it untill you find the place where you should position it over the circle. Waste of time...

Now, you can just load different bodies/eyes/hairs and so on, place them, and you got a customized player!

Comment: Thanks! but, how do i use it to make them customized? i mean, when the player buys a new eye color for example, how do i make the program change automatically? and also, where in the program do i put all of my voids? its confusing.. Thanks!

Comment: Create a class `Player`, save it instance (To a file, for example) when the user exits the game and load it back when he launches it back. Then, in this class you can have some fields to hold values the hair color, eyes color etc... Then, each time the game is reloaded changes will be seen; However, you can reload new textures when the user changes his customization. What do you mean by "my voids"?

Comment: for example :  public void buyItem(){

if(money>moneyNeeded){
eyecolor = blue;
}

}

Comment: Exactly :) If you want to change the eye color while in-game (And not to wait untill the next launch) you should also reload all textures and reorganize them on the `BitmapTextureAtlas` with the new options.

Comment: the only thing i didn't understand is where to put it and where to use it.. can you include an example in your answer to how to use it properly? how do i reload the BitmapTextureAtlas? and how do i even use all of these stuff.. until now i have been using the beginning android games framework and now im using this one, im new to the frame work and started using it yesterday. Are there any tutorials that you recommend me to watch/read? Thanks!

Comment: דרך אגב ראיתי בפרופיל שלך שאתה מישראל, אתה מדבר עיברית?

אם כן אתה יכול בבקשה לעזור לי דרך האימייל שלי? Baruchadi@gmail.com

תודה מראש!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Jong's solution won't work, at least not in GLES1 version of AndEngine. When I tried to combine sprites this way, the latest one just overwrote anything that was under it. In this case, only the eyes would appear on the screen.